# Mambo parrot /tello control propeller speeds

Tags: control, quadcopter, drone, parrot

From my understanding, for parrot mambo and tello drones, we control forward-backward, up-dow, left-right, and yaw speeds (in m/s and deg/s). But the low level control is control the 4 propeller speeds. I was wondering if there is a 1-1 map between these two control options, meaning that if I have the input for the 4 propeller speeds, I know the forward-backward, up-dow, left-right, and yaw speeds  and viceverse.
In this way, we would be able to control the low level even if the interface of these drones do not allow us to do it.
Thanks!

Comment: this question is a better fit at https://drones.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

No, those two things are not 1:1. Remember that you have a dynamic system. The drone's current velocity can have a big impact on what happens to the propeller speeds when you give a new **desired** velocity.